# Python, scrapy: Unable to paginate dynamically generated links on website, using the link got from firebug

Tags: python, ajax, get

I am a complete newbie at python, scrapy and web scraping, this being my first learning project.

I want to scrape multiple pages from this [website](http://intheloop.com.sg/yoga-studios-directory/) using scrapy:

The links seem to be generated using AJAX. At the end of the page is the link to next page. Clicking on `<2>` or `<next>` and checking the link generated on firebug, shows following request being generated:

```
GET directory?p=2&category=1&map[disable]=0&map[height]=500&map[list_height]=500&map[span]=5&map[style]=&map[list_show]=0&map[listing_default_zoom]=15&map[options][scrollwheel]=0&map[options][marker_clusters]=1&map[options][force_fit_bounds]=0&distance=0&is_mile=0&zoom=15&perpage=16&scroll_list=0&feature=1&featured_only=0&hide_searchbox=0&hide_nav=0&hide_nav_views=0&hide_pager=0&template=&grid_columns=4&sort=title
```

So I thought, in my limited understanding, that if I replace `p={pagenum}` with any page number, that should get me the required page. I tried using the following url to directly request for the page:

```
http://intheloop.com.sg/sabai/directory?p=2&category=1&map[disable]=0&map[height]=500&map[list_height]=500&map[span]=5&map[style]=&map[list_show]=0&map[listing_default_zoom]=15&map[options][scrollwheel]=0&map[options][marker_clusters]=1&map[options][force_fit_bounds]=0&distance=0&is_mile=0&zoom=15&perpage=16&scroll_list=0&feature=1&featured_only=0&hide_searchbox=0&hide_nav=0&hide_nav_views=0&hide_pager=0&template=&grid_columns=4&sort=title
```

However, this link generates an error page saying

> page not found

Can anyone help me understand what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a slight modification in the ajax url to achieve this,

check the demo from the scrapy shell:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: next_page_data = response.xpath('//div[@class="sabai-pull-right sabai-pagination"]/ul/li/a[contains(text(), "Next")]/@onclick').extract()

In [3]: next_page_data
Out[3]: [u"SABAI.ajax({scrollTo:'#sabai-directory-listings',trigger:jQuery(this), target:'#sabai-directory-listings', url:'http://intheloop.com.sg/sabai/directory?p=2&category=1&map%5Bdisable%5D=0&map%5Bheight%5D=500&map%5Blist_height%5D=500&map%5Bspan%5D=5&map%5Bstyle%5D=&map%5Blist_show%5D=0&map%5Blisting_default_zoom%5D=15&map%5Boptions%5D%5Bscrollwheel%5D=0&map%5Boptions%5D%5Bmarker_clusters%5D=1&map%5Boptions%5D%5Bforce_fit_bounds%5D=0&distance=0&is_mile=0&zoom=15&perpage=16&scroll_list=0&feature=1&featured_only=0&hide_searchbox=0&hide_nav=0&hide_nav_views=0&hide_pager=0&template=&addons=&grid_columns=4&sort=title'}); return false;"]

In [4]: url = re.findall(r'url\:\'(.*)\'\}', next_page_data[0])

In [5]: url 
Out[5]: [u'http://intheloop.com.sg/sabai/directory?p=2&category=1&map%5Bdisable%5D=0&map%5Bheight%5D=500&map%5Blist_height%5D=500&map%5Bspan%5D=5&map%5Bstyle%5D=&map%5Blist_show%5D=0&map%5Blisting_default_zoom%5D=15&map%5Boptions%5D%5Bscrollwheel%5D=0&map%5Boptions%5D%5Bmarker_clusters%5D=1&map%5Boptions%5D%5Bforce_fit_bounds%5D=0&distance=0&is_mile=0&zoom=15&perpage=16&scroll_list=0&feature=1&featured_only=0&hide_searchbox=0&hide_nav=0&hide_nav_views=0&hide_pager=0&template=&addons=&grid_columns=4&sort=title']

In [6]: nex_page_url = url[0] + '&__ajax=%23sabai-directory-listings&_='

In [7]: nex_page_url 
Out[7]: u'http://intheloop.com.sg/sabai/directory?p=2&category=1&map%5Bdisable%5D=0&map%5Bheight%5D=500&map%5Blist_height%5D=500&map%5Bspan%5D=5&map%5Bstyle%5D=&map%5Blist_show%5D=0&map%5Blisting_default_zoom%5D=15&map%5Boptions%5D%5Bscrollwheel%5D=0&map%5Boptions%5D%5Bmarker_clusters%5D=1&map%5Boptions%5D%5Bforce_fit_bounds%5D=0&distance=0&is_mile=0&zoom=15&perpage=16&scroll_list=0&feature=1&featured_only=0&hide_searchbox=0&hide_nav=0&hide_nav_views=0&hide_pager=0&template=&addons=&grid_columns=4&sort=title&__ajax=%23sabai-directory-listings&_='
```

in the `AJAX` request you can find two extra parameters `__ajax` and `_` at the end of the `url` and appending those extra parameter will give you the proper url.